# Returning JSON in Koa

Tags: node.js, koa

I receive JSON by POST method in my router which I then return to the user. For some reason the returned JSON will have all numerical and boolean values casted to string. I am using koa-bodyparser if thats relevant.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Code:

```
var js = ctx.request.body.json;
ctx.body = {
                status: 'success',
                json: js
};
```

Input JSON:

```
{
"json": {
       "numbers": 123
        }
}
```

Output JSON:

```
{
"json": {
       "numbers": "123"
        }
}
```

Comment: Use strict mode true. Is it not helpful to you?

Comment: @Hardik Shah: How do I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

Strict mode is already active by default (https://github.com/cojs/co-body#options) so you don't need to worry about it. This code works for me:

```
  ctx.body = {
    status: 'success',
    json: ctx.request.body.json
  };
```

I used Postman to send it to the koa server and received the answer in Postman which was:

```
  {
    "status": "success",
    "json": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Joe"
    }
  }
```

As you can see the 'id' is a number. As you did not write about your client I assume it could be the browser? If so try to use the JSON.parse() function because you may get a string from your post-request. See this example:

```
JSON.parse("{\"json\":{\"id\":1}}");
```

You can also try Postman as client and see if that works (https://www.getpostman.com/).

Comment: I used this as input in Postman: ```{
 "json": {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Joe"
 }
}```